# Django best way to support developer specific config/settings

Tags: python, django

Here is the method my company devised, just wondering if anyone has anything better:

In Settings.py (at the bottom)

```
#...

try:
    if socket.gethostname() == 'testsite':
        from myir.local.TEST_settings import *
    elif socket.gethostname() == 'prod':
        from myir.local.PROD_settings import *
    else:
        from myir.local.DEV_settings import *
        try:
            # dev settings - don't commit local_settings.py
            from proj.local.local_settings import *
        except:
            print "no local dev settings found..."
            pass # intentionally do nothing.

except ImportError:
    pass
```

local_settings.py:

```
DEBUG = True

LOGGING = { .. }  # i usually keep maximum aount of logging possible in my dev environment.

... other configs you might want to override.
```

Comment: that's not an uncommon way of doing it.  Though I personally prefer using a deployment system so that the config file that prod needs lives on the deployment server or on the prod server.  Then at deployment time either system floats in the proper config or we get the config from a environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

Django provides the environment variable [`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE) to specify the settings module to use. You can specify `settings.my_prod_module` there which enables settings to be different on production. Locally you can specify a different value.

You can also specify the value in your WSGI file:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings.my_prod_module'
```